# Qt canonical way of retrieving values from Wizard / Dialog on accepted / finished signal

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, dialog, signals

I'm using PyQt, but I guess the same questions also applies to Qt C++.

Assume that I have a main window with a button that opens a wizard that collects data and that data needs to be used in the main window after the wizard has closed. standard procedure.

So there are multiple ways to do this. either I can pass a reference to the main window to the Wizard and it does all the work using the main window reference, but I'd say that breaks modularity. I can also wire up a callback to the wizard `accepted` `rejected` or `finished` signal, but in that callback, I don't have a reference to the wizard itself, so I cannot get to the data in the wizards fields. Unless I store a reference to the wizard as instance variable in order to access it again from the callback.

Another option is (even though I haven't fully understood it yet) to get a reference to the emitter of the signal (i.e. the wizard) in the callback using https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender. But that seems not recommended.

So whats the canonical way?

Answer (score 1):

Premise: this is a bit of an opinion based question, as there is not *one and only* "good" way to do that. I just wanted to comment (opinion based answer/questions are discouraged here in SO), but the limited formatting isn't very helpful.

"Passing a reference" doesn't necessarily break modularity.
Instead, that's exactly what QDialog usually are initialized: the parent is the "calling" window, which is also how a QDialog can be "modal" to the parent or the whole application (meaning that no interaction outside the dialog is allowed as long as it is active).

AFAIK, I don't know if this is actually considered *canonical*, but the following is the most commonly suggested approach.
The idea is that you have a child object (a QDialog, usually) which might or might not be initialized everytime you need it, that's up to you; the important part is that you need a reference to it at least for the time required to update its result, which can even happen within the scope of a single method/slot.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyWizard(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('check')
        layout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.input)
        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        layout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def setData(self, **data):
        self.checkBox.setChecked(data.get('check', False))
        self.input.setText(data.get('text', ''))

    def getData(self):
        return {'check': self.checkBox.isChecked(), 'text': self.input.text()}

    def exec_(self, **data):
        self.setData(**data)
        return super().exec_()


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.showWizBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show wizard')
        layout.addWidget(self.showWizBtn)
        self.showWizBtn.clicked.connect(self.getDataFromWizard)
        self.data = {}

    def getDataFromWizard(self):
        wiz = MyWizard(self)
        if wiz.exec_(**self.data):
            self.data.update(wiz.getData())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another possibility is to create a persistent child dialog (but keep in mind that if the data can be changed by the parent, you'll have to find a way to update it, at least when executed); the concept here is that you can exec the dialog whenever you need, and you have the `accepted` signal connected to a slot that can get the data from the dialog. This is not a common use (nor very suggested IMHO) and should be used only for very specific scenarios.

As you already found out, using `sender` is not suggested: signals are asynchronous, and while in normal conditions the sender is reliable it's better to avoid using it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Interesting approach, certainly gave me new ideas. But the use of `exec` is [discouraged in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec). A cleaner way would be to use the signals such as `accept` but then the reference to the wizard is missing.It pretty much contradicts exactly what you said in the last paragraph about signals being discouraged.

Comment: Actually, the documentation is self-contradicting as in it suggests using `exec` for modal dialogs in the general usage section...